# Using dynamic realm in android

Tags: android, realm

Is there anyone used dynamic realm in android.I'm searching a lot in net but I cannot find any sample code using dynamic realm database, except [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#dynamic-realms) realm documentation in android

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    DynamicRealm realm1 = DynamicRealm.getInstance(realmConfig);

 // In a DynamicRealm all objects are DynamicRealmObjects
    DynamicRealmObject person = realm1.createObject("Person");

// All fields are accessed using strings
    String name = person.getString("name");
    int age = person.getInt("age");

// An underlying schema still exists, so accessing a field that does not exist
// will throw an exception
    person.getString("I don't exist");

// Queries still work normally
    RealmResults<DynamicRealmObject> persons = realm1.where("Person")
            .equalTo("name", "John")
            .findAll();
```

but when I run this code I'm getting this error message.

```
  The class class_Person doesn't exist in this Realm.
```

can anyone help me about this and show me a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DynamicRealm does not automatically generate any schemas, so if you have a `Person` model class, you cannot access it dynamically before you opened a Realm normally using `Realm.getInstance()` (as that will create the schema). Otherwise you manually have to create the Person class using `DynamicRealm.getSchema()`

Comment: Hi thanks for your attention but can you show me a full sample code using dynamic realm?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to. Our migration example uses DynamicRealm for example: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java

Answer (score 1):

in order to create new instance of the existing schema in the realmDB  you have to create an instance by calling realm method createObject inside realm method beginTransaction and commitTransaction  like mentioned below.

```
realm.beginTransaction();
DynamicRealmObject person = realm.createObject("Person");
person.setString("name", "kiran");
person.setInt("age", 29);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

and the methods setString and setInt are the methods of the DynamicRealmObject.
 Please go through the documentation [https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/DynamicRealm.html](http://%20https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/DynamicRealm.html) for more understanding of the DynamicRealms.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer, rather as giving a piece of code :)

Comment: @Bram please go through the documentation for better understanding.
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/DynamicRealm.html

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/DynamicRealmObject.html